# Как проверить есть ли в переменной String значение

Tags: java, android

Как проверить есть ли в переменной String значение.
String key;

Comment: Можно задать изначально String key = null и потом проверить его на null

Answer (score 1):

```
if(str  != null && !str.isEmpty()) {
    // do something
}
```

Проверьте на null и на наличие символов в строке, как на примере выше